# Javascript: How can I remove appended child row (tr)?

Tags: javascript

I am using JS to append array data to a table.

I am trying to add a button that removes the appended data, and puts its own data in instead.  I can get the data to be added, but I cant get the data removed.

I have tried these with no luck -

```
.children().last().remove();
```

&

```
           .removeChild() ;
```

I have a fiddle but I cant get the original data remove when new added (button now works! -thanks) - http://jsfiddle.net/2waZ2/37/
What code do I add so when the new line from the array is added the old data is removed?

Code to append on load:

```
var row =  document.createElement('tr');
row.innerHTML = displayArrayAsTable(QR4, 24, 25);
document.getElementById('mytable').appendChild( row ) ;
```

Button code to add data:

```
function addNewRow() {
var row =  document.createElement('tr');
row.innerHTML = displayArrayAsTable(QR4L, 24, 25);
 document.getElementById('mytable').appendChild( row ) ;
}
```

Comment: have you considered using jQuery for this?

Comment: Fixed jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2waZ2/37/

Comment: Use `no wrap (body)` on fiddle

Comment: can you give an example of how that would help?  The fiddle has jq loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2waZ2/47/

Removing the 1st child row:

```
var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
table.removeChild(table.children[1])
```

Comment: brilliant - thanks.  How would I remove all children except for [0]? Is there a shorthand?

Comment: `for(var i = 1; i < table.children.length; i++) table.removeChild(table.children[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikaoelitiana/2waZ2/49/) and it works fine now.
You can use something like this before adding the new row:

```
var last = document.getElementById('mytable').lastChild ;    
document.getElementById('mytable').removeChild(last);
```

Comment: Thats a great relative answer and saves a lot a code.  Took me a while to understand it.  Thanks!

Comment: if last already has  document.getElementById('mytable') in it, why does it have to be repeated?  Can the var last not be called on its own?  removeChild(last);?

Comment: I think it's needed because removeChild is a DOM function and needs to be called from a DOM Object. But what you can do would be to set the table in a var and call only that var instead of repeating document.getElementById('mytable') 
Somthing like : `var mytable = document.getElementById('mytable');
var last = mytable.lastChild;
mytable.removeChild(last)`
- 
[demo updated](http://jsfiddle.net/mikaoelitiana/2waZ2/50/)

Answer (score 0):

A trivial answer with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/guard/2waZ2/48/